# Getting reserved IPs from router to Hyper-V VMs

Tags: windows-10, networking, router, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have two Ubuntu virtual machines running inside Hyper-V under Windows 10. I need to allow remote access to both of these machines, as well as host. 
For this I created an external switch and enabled "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter". I have single controller card (LAN) in host, which is selected for connecting this switch to. 
In both vm, I used this switch and assigned a static MAC address, and in router assigned static IP to both MAC address. 
Now when running vm, I encounter the scenario where host gets correct reserved IP from router, first VM also gets correct IP from router. But second VM is getting dynamic IP address. I checked in router page, and correct mac address is published from virtual machine, but the IP assigned is still dynamic. 
 
Since this is first time I am running Hyper-V for my project, I am not sure where the root problem is. I verified mac address are not conflicted, correct MAC address is published to router page, and DHCP binding is also correct. Any advise on what to do next will be helpful.
The router is provided by ISP, which is ZTE F660. The host is running Windows 10 Pro 21H1.

Here are the screenshots of settings chosen:
[image]

Then added same switch to both VMs: 
[image]

Then assigned two separate MAC address to both machine, under individual VM Network Adapters, and added binding rules in router:
[image]

Comment: Are the VMs connected as NAT or Bridged? Please give more details about the IP addresses used and the router's settings (especially port-forwarding).

Comment: Both VMs are connected to virtual switch, which is configured with External network. From my understanding, this will be bridged mode. I haven't set port-forwarding rules yet, as the IP assigned by router is dynamic. I used DHCP binding in router's configuration to map mac address to specific IP.

Comment: If you're trying to connect from outside of your local network, you need port-forwarding.

Comment: Yes, agreed. Currently I am directly accessing host and validating everything is correct before enabling port forwarding and accessing it remotely. It wont work even if port forwarding is done if IP address assigned is not same. What I see is dynamic IP allocation to VM, so I stopped myself in initial step

Comment: You either assign static IPs to all devices or, depending on the router, by device name or MAC address or whatever the router can accept.

Comment: Yes, so I am assigning static IP based on MAC address, which is acceptable in my router. I assigned different static MAC address to both VMs. In router page, it shows 3 device connected (2 VM and 1 host). It assigns host and VM reserved IP, but random IP for 2nd VM.

Comment: Your last comment seems to conflict with your question.

Answer (score 0):

> I created an external switch and enabled "Allow management operating
> system to share this network adapter".

This is correct. I have this setup here with a Kali VM having an IP on my external router. I always get the IP I set.

You also need to set the Guest Machine network settings and I did not see that you did that.

Here is a screenshot of the Guest settings.  Make sure each Guest is set for Bridged Networking.  This is in addition to the setting for External.  I get the same IP on my external router all the time.

[image: Set for Bridged Networking]

Comment: Yup, I did select the virtual switch as newly created switch (the bridged external switch) for both VMs. Both vms are assigned to same switch.
"In both vm, I used this switch and assigned a static MAC address, and in router assigned static IP to both MAC address."

Comment: Make sure the MAC addresses are different for each guest and then review your router settings for DHCP reservation for those addresses. Then the Guest machines and host Hyper-V machine should be restarted (I would)

Comment: Yes, I came to know about dynamic behaviour post reboot of host machine. I added screenshots to add more clarity. I didn't anticipate it being unclear on what configuration I have selected